# I Want To Delete A specific Contact number Among Contact Using ABaddressbook in iOS With Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, contacts

I want to remove a `specific contact number` as like in contact I have more then one contact number like `work,home etc` if I want to delete a specific field as for an example I want to delete work or home filed of number without deleting the whole record so how can I delete that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete one number of iphone contact which has multiple numbers in the contact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652640/how-to-delete-one-number-of-iphone-contact-which-has-multiple-numbers-in-the-con)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not remove that from app but you can edit info from contact list.