# How to add new contact into Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, contacts

I have a "+" button in my app, and when I tapped, I want to navigate to the "new contact" screen (like the image below).

[image]

I have found the same question here: [iOS - add contact into Contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625447/ios-add-contact-into-contacts) but the code is not up to date.
I want a solution in Swift 5.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactviewcontroller/1616922-init

Comment: The answers are not “too old”. This is unchanged.

Comment: I mean the code is not up to date if you don't understand. Thank you!

Comment: The code is up to date and I do understand. Did you look at the documentation link I gave you?

Comment: Αs I have already written, I want an answer in Swift 5. Thanks for the link that you gave me. I already take the answer that I want by @Lalitkumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Contacts      // import these framework
import ContactsUI

//--- Your Button Action
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any)
{
    let openContact = CNContact()
    let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: openContact)
     vc.delegate = self // this delegate CNContactViewControllerDelegate
   // self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc), animated:true)
}


func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The code is working but I get a strange "bug" on animation and also the cancel button doesn't work

Comment: I get an error on  vc.delegate = self (Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'CNContactViewControllerDelegate?')

Comment: I fix it by adding CNContactViewControllerDelegate on my controller. Thanks!